# How do you highlight a text area when you put a cursor over it?

Tags: jquery, textbox, highlight

Im trying to activate or highlight the text area, when you put the cursor over it. 
Where am i Going wrong?

```
$focus('#contactForm').on('mouseenter mouseleave mouseup', function(e) {
$(this).toggleClass('Highlight');
$(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
if (e.type == 'mouseup') {
$(this).text('X: ' + e.pageX + ' Y: ' + e.pageY);
}
});
```

Comment: Just use the CSS `:hover` state. It was made for this.

Comment: Im trying to use jquery and trying to have the blank text box get highlighted when you are in it. So users know where they are at on the page.

Comment: Using jQuery to highlight an element in hover is like using a sword to peel a grape. Use CSS. Either the `:active` or `:hover` selectors.

Comment: ok Thanks. I appreciate the help